# How to pair and connect to a headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, low-level, headset

How can I connect and disconnect to/from a headset bluetooth device programmatically?

The application should work for Android 2.1+

In other words: I have a headeset. I can pair, connect, disconnect to it using Settings/Wireless and Networks/Blutooth Settings.

But how can I do all those things (pair, connect, disconnect) from my program?

Answer (score 2):

Please chech [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) link.

The android bluetooth example (already listed) has a bunch of issues (not the least of which is you need 2 android devices to get it to function).

Take a look at the example at http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/ where he is using bt on the android device to hit a server (to do some robotics work).

Be aware of UUID issues (the way that BT decides what connection it can make is defined in the UUID), and check out http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/doc/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html

Keep in mind that the 16 bits represented in the UUID (ie, 0x1101 for Serial Port) is misleading in that its really the least significant part and needs to be coded 0x00001101.